# How to create a Mongo Docker Image with default collections and data?

Tags: mongodb, docker, dockerfile

I need support here to build my own mongo docker image.

I have a list of scripts to create and insert data into the MongoDB that shall be called in my Dockerfile to deliver a docker image with default collections and data.

Here is how my Dockerfile looks like currently:

```
FROM mongo:latest

RUN mkdir -p /data/scripts

COPY . /data/scripts

RUN mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log --dbpath /data/db/

RUN FILES=scripts/*-create.js
RUN for f in $FILES; do mongo mydb $f; done

RUN FILES=scripts/*-insert.js
RUN for f in $FILES; do mongo mydb $f; done

RUN mongod --shutdown
```

I've tried different options to start and stop mongod and always one of the two fail, the current script raise the following error:

```
There doesn't seem to be a server running with dbpath: /data/db
```

**Update**

After @Matt answer I could run successfully the command chain, but can't still see my database (called my-db), collections and data there.

The current Dockerfile:

```
FROM mongo:latest

RUN mkdir -p /data/db/scripts

COPY . /data/db

RUN mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log --dbpath /data/db \
    && CREATE_FILES=/data/db/scripts/*-create.js \
    && for f in $CREATE_FILES; do mongo 127.0.0.1:27017 $f; done \
    && INSERT_FILES=/data/db/scripts/*-insert.js \
    && for f in $INSERT_FILES; do mongo 127.0.0.1:27017 $f; done \
    && mongod --shutdown
```

The output from the docker build command:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 10.24 kB
Step 1 : FROM mongo:latest
 ---> c08c92f4cb13
Step 2 : RUN mkdir -p /data/db/scripts
 ---> Running in a7088943bb57
 ---> 373c7319927d
Removing intermediate container a7088943bb57
Step 3 : COPY . /data/db
 ---> 8fa84884edb7
Removing intermediate container ae43e2c24fee
Step 4 : RUN mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log --dbpath /data/db     && CREATE_FILES=/data/db/scripts/*-create.js    && for f in $CREATE_FILES; do mongo 127.0.0.1:27017 $f; done    && INSERT_FILES=/data/db/scripts/*-insert.js    && for f in $INSERT_FILES; do mongo 127.0.0.1:27017 $f; done    && mongod --shutdown
 ---> Running in 33970b6865ee
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 10
child process started successfully, parent exiting
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.7
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017/test
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.7
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017/test
killing process with pid: 10
 ---> 8451e43b7749
Removing intermediate container 33970b6865ee
Successfully built 8451e43b7749
```

But as I said, I still can't see the database, collections and data in my database using mongo shell.
Also I connected to the running container and got the mongodb.log:

```
2015-11-06T16:15:14.562+0000 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
2015-11-06T16:15:14.562+0000 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2015-11-06T16:15:14.698+0000 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] preallocateIsFaster=true 2.36
2015-11-06T16:15:14.746+0000 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread started
2015-11-06T16:15:14.746+0000 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread started
2015-11-06T16:15:14.747+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=10 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=9c05d483673a
2015-11-06T16:15:14.747+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
2015-11-06T16:15:14.747+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2015-11-06T16:15:14.747+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2015-11-06T16:15:14.747+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2015-11-06T16:15:14.747+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2015-11-06T16:15:14.747+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2015-11-06T16:15:14.747+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2015-11-06T16:15:14.747+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2015-11-06T16:15:14.747+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2015-11-06T16:15:14.747+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.7
2015-11-06T16:15:14.747+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 6ce7cbe8c6b899552dadd907604559806aa2e9bd
2015-11-06T16:15:14.747+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-183-78-195 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.46-1 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2015-11-06T16:15:14.747+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2015-11-06T16:15:14.747+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { processManagement: { fork: true }, storage: { dbPath: "/data/db" }, systemLog: { destination: "file", path: "/var/log/mongodb.log" } }
2015-11-06T16:15:14.748+0000 I INDEX    [initandlisten] allocating new ns file /data/db/local.ns, filling with zeroes...
2015-11-06T16:15:14.802+0000 I STORAGE  [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /data/db/local.0, filling with zeroes...
2015-11-06T16:15:14.802+0000 I STORAGE  [FileAllocator] creating directory /data/db/_tmp
2015-11-06T16:15:14.804+0000 I STORAGE  [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /data/db/local.0, size: 64MB,  took 0 secs
2015-11-06T16:15:14.807+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2015-11-06T16:15:14.830+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:49641 #1 (1 connection now open)
2015-11-06T16:15:14.832+0000 I INDEX    [conn1] allocating new ns file /data/db/my-db.ns, filling with zeroes...
2015-11-06T16:15:14.897+0000 I STORAGE  [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /data/db/my-db.0, filling with zeroes...
2015-11-06T16:15:14.898+0000 I STORAGE  [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /data/db/my-db.0, size: 64MB,  took 0 secs
2015-11-06T16:15:14.904+0000 I NETWORK  [conn1] end connection 127.0.0.1:49641 (0 connections now open)
2015-11-06T16:15:14.945+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:49642 #2 (1 connection now open)
2015-11-06T16:15:14.958+0000 I NETWORK  [conn2] end connection 127.0.0.1:49642 (0 connections now open)
2015-11-06T16:15:14.982+0000 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends
2015-11-06T16:15:14.982+0000 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] now exiting
2015-11-06T16:15:14.982+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2015-11-06T16:15:14.982+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 6
2015-11-06T16:15:14.982+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 7
2015-11-06T16:15:14.982+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2015-11-06T16:15:14.982+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2015-11-06T16:15:14.982+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2015-11-06T16:15:14.982+0000 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2015-11-06T16:15:14.982+0000 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: final commit...
2015-11-06T16:15:15.008+0000 I JOURNAL  [signalProcessingThread] journalCleanup...
2015-11-06T16:15:15.008+0000 I JOURNAL  [signalProcessingThread] removeJournalFiles
2015-11-06T16:15:15.009+0000 I JOURNAL  [signalProcessingThread] Terminating durability thread ...
2015-11-06T16:15:15.088+0000 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread stopped
2015-11-06T16:15:15.088+0000 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread stopped
2015-11-06T16:15:15.088+0000 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: closing all files...
2015-11-06T16:15:15.090+0000 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] closeAllFiles() finished
2015-11-06T16:15:15.090+0000 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2015-11-06T16:15:15.090+0000 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] dbexit:  rc: 0
```

I also checked the folder /data/db content:

```
root@fbaf17233182:/data/db# ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 3 mongodb mongodb 4096 Nov  6 16:15 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root    root    4096 Nov  6 16:15 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root    4096 Nov  5 18:55 scripts
```

May help:

- [Parent Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/982328582c74dd2f0a9c8c77b84006f291f974c3/3.0/Dockerfile)
- Parent Dockerfile [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/982328582c74dd2f0a9c8c77b84006f291f974c3/3.0/docker-entrypoint.sh)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The problem was that information could not be saved on `/db/data`, so I've created a solution creating my own data directory.

```
# Parent Dockerfile https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/982328582c74dd2f0a9c8c77b84006f291f974c3/3.0/Dockerfile
FROM mongo:latest

# Modify child mongo to use /data/db2 as dbpath (because /data/db wont persist the build)
RUN mkdir -p /data/db2 \
    && echo "dbpath = /data/db2" > /etc/mongodb.conf \
    && chown -R mongodb:mongodb /data/db2

COPY . /data/db2

RUN mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log --dbpath /data/db2 --smallfiles \
    && CREATE_FILES=/data/db2/scripts/*-create.js \
    && for f in $CREATE_FILES; do mongo 127.0.0.1:27017 $f; done \
    && INSERT_FILES=/data/db2/scripts/*-insert.js \
    && for f in $INSERT_FILES; do mongo 127.0.0.1:27017 $f; done \
    && mongod --dbpath /data/db2 --shutdown \
    && chown -R mongodb /data/db2

# Make the new dir a VOLUME to persists it 
VOLUME /data/db2

CMD ["mongod", "--config", "/etc/mongodb.conf", "--smallfiles"]
```

Thanks to @yosifkit from the [docker-library/mongo](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/64#issuecomment-154501303) Github project for pointing that the volume would store the data in the resulting image. I missed that on the documentation.

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out myself. Why is it that the data doesn't persist?

Comment: @Sergio data does not persist in a VOLUME because it was added after the VOLUME was created and so it will stay at that state until a container is created based on the image. If you add data in a directory before volume creation it will be persisted.

Comment: This was real essential. Making sure that specify VOLUME after modifying data.

RUN mkdir -p /data/db
ADD seedMongoDB.js .
RUN $MONGOD_START && mongo tembowms-dev --quiet seedMongoDB.js && mongod --shutdown

VOLUME /data/db

Answer (score 11):

During a docker image build, each build command like `RUN` is launched in it's own docker container and then when the command completes the data is committed as an image. If you run [`dockviz images --tree`](https://github.com/justone/dockviz) while doing a build you will get the idea.

In your case `mongod` has started and stopped long before you need it. You need to start mongo and run your scripts all in the one `RUN` step. You can achieve that by using a shell script that launches mongod and inserts your data.

Your `Dockerfile` will run:

```
RUN mongo_create_insert.sh
```

Then `mongo_create_insert.sh` contains all your mongo dependent steps:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log --dbpath /data/db/

FILES=scripts/*-create.js
for f in $FILES; do mongo mydb $f; done

FILES=scripts/*-insert.js
for f in $FILES; do mongo mydb $f; done

mongod --shutdown
```

As a side note, I tend to install Ansible in my base image and use that to provision Docker images in single `RUN` command rather than doing lots of shell RUN steps in a Dockerfile (which is just a glorified shell script in the end). You lose some of the build caching niceness but we've moved on from provisioning with shell scripts for a reason.

Comment: Thanks @Matt, this was a very nice explanation and now I could get the script running. Although it run successfully, I still can't see the db created in my running container. If I run the same commands on the running container I get the db and the collections created as expected but I'm not able to create a docker image that have a default database, collections and data.  I will update the answer with the new details.

Comment: shouldn't this script also wait for mongodb to start?

Comment: `mongod` doesn't fork until it is ready to accept connections.

Answer (score 7):

According to the description of the image on DockerHub, there is a  much cleaner and simpler solution for this.

> When a container is started for the first time it will execute files
>   with extensions .sh and .js that are found in
>   /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files will be executed in alphabetical
>   order. .js files will be executed by mongo using the database
>   specified by the MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE variable, if it is present, or
>   test otherwise. You may also switch databases within the .js script.

First, the Dockerfile is as simple as

```
FROM mongo:4
COPY setup.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
COPY scripts /
```

Then, in the `setup.sh`, add your user/collection creation script, for example

```
mongo=( mongo --host 127.0.0.1 --port 27017 --quiet )
mongo+=(
    --username="$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME"
    --password="$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD"
    --authenticationDatabase="$rootAuthDatabase"
)

CREATE_FILES=/scripts/*-create.js 
for f in $CREATE_FILES; do "${mongo[@]}" "$MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE" $f; done 

INSERT_FILES=/scripts/*-insert.js 
for f in $INSERT_FILES; do "${mongo[@]}" "$MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE" $f; done
```