# How to create a MongoDB docker and save the DB's configuration?

Tags: mongodb, docker, dockerfile

I pretty new with dockers and started to play with it during my last project.
I have a MongoDB container which I wish to move between some machines during the development.

I have some questions regards it-

1. Is there an option to copy-paste all the DB data? Mean that when I copy the image container I will be able to copy the DB's data as well? I tried to copy the related directory on my machine but it wasn't worked well (copying the host directory in `-v host_directory:container_directory`)
2. Is there a way that I can create a `Dockerfile` that builds a mongo image and configures the DB? Such as set a new admin user, create DBs - so when I build the docker image all the settings and schemes will be the same?

Thanks ahead!

Comment: I think here are the answers you are looking for: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20652410/4787945 2. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33601894/4787945

Comment: I had the same case so I created an sh script that builds a MongoDB cluster (docker run commands) and then via a series of docker exec commands I copy scripts that create users inside the containers and execute them (via docker exec). Finally, I also copy in the same way a previously created dump that contains all DBs and then restore it via mongorestore.